# Are there drawbacks of cache in usb drives?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb-flash-drive, cache, portable-apps

### Background

A few years ago I was glad to find out that there is a new flash drive with on-board caching (the [SuperTalent Express RAM Cache](http://www.supertalent.com/products/stt_usb_detail.php?type=Express%20RAM%20Cache)), which gave it a really neat performance on small files.
I like running portable apps from my flash drive, as well as occasionally boot/run my operating system from an usb stick, so I was really happy that this technology was finally coming.

It seems to me (also from benchmarks) that this was a step towards having a small SSD with the form factor of a flash drive, really something with potential and demand (imho).

But since then quite a few years have passed, and this drive seems to still be the only one of it's kind.

### The Question

So I was wondering if there are some drawbacks about hardware cached usb-flash-drives or something else that I am overlooking, since neither this company nor anyone else continued developing new devices with this capability.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There doesn't need to be a drawback for a product not to take off; it just doesn't have to solve a big enough problem to overcome inertia. See http://www.jwz.org/doc/worse-is-better.html

Comment: or simply not be cost effective

Comment: You both might be right there (good article btw). It is still kind of sad though.